# I'm getting repeated Careers items in my inbox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, global-inbox

A few days back, I got a careers item in my inbox (employer interest - awesome!). I replied to the employer, and they haven't gotten back to me yet, but every day or so the careers item pops up in my inbox again. Is this somehow by design? It kind of seems like a bug to me, given that I've already replied, and they haven't done anything else.

Clarification: By 'inbox', I mean the lovely little StackExchange 'inbox' that is on the upper left hand corner of all SE sites, NOT my e-mail. Sorry for the confusion. I did only get one e-mail, but the SE inbox is repeatedly showing up.

Comment: is it possible for you to take a screenshot of this when it happens and send it to team@stackoverflow.com?  It's an interesting case.

Comment: I'll take a screenshot if it occurs again. It hasn't happened since I posted. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

We have checked the global inbox database and verified the message only shows up once.  We also verified that last inbox view date is being set correctly.  We then tried numerous things to reproduce your issue with the message getting the highlight even after you have cleared the inbox.  Unfortunately we are unable to reproduce the issue.

Can you give some more detail as to exactly what is happening?  Are you getting other messages on top of Careers notification and then the Careers notification pops back above messages that were previously on top of it?  Is the Careers message highlighting again?  Are you getting a red circle in the UI indicating that you need to click the inbox again?

Has this happened again since you posted this question and can you post a screen shot of this if it happens again?

Comment: I don't know details on either side, but the wording of the OP's message ("pops up in my inbox") seems like it's referring to the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ Inbox rather than an email inbox.

Comment: Yep, I mean SE inbox, not e-mail inbox. I clarified the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  We're currently looking into this.

Comment: @MichaelKohne I have edited the response with some more info.